# How can I remove the non-visible part of `clip-path`?

Tags: css, clip-path

I would like to cut out images that vary in size at a height of 50% each.

So I thought about using the inset method of the `clip-path` property. But, in this property, the cut out space remains as height.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
}

.img {
  flex: 1;
  background: #900;
}

.img+.img {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 45% 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x550/009/fff.png" alt>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/090/fff.png" alt>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x150/09f/fff.png" alt>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I used `overflow: hidden` and`height` to edit the source code as follows:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  height: 100vh;
}

.img {
  flex: 1;
  background: #900;
  height: 45%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img+.img {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x550/009/fff.png" alt>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/090/fff.png" alt>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x150/09f/fff.png" alt>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, it will be 45% of the height of the parent container, not 45% of the height of the image.

Why is this behavior? And how do I cut out 50% of the height of each image and get rid of the extra space?

Answer (score 1):

Percentage height is relative to the parent element and in this case you are facing a complex behavior where the `45%` is the height of the tallest image that is defining the parent height.

One idea to obtain what you want is to consider scaling where you up scale the image twice and you down scale the container twice:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  height: 100vh;
}

.img {
  flex: 1;
  background: #900;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform:scaleY(0.5);
  transform-origin:top;
}

.img+.img {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform:scaleY(2);
  transform-origin:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x550/009/fff.png" alt>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/090/fff.png" alt>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x150/09f/fff.png" alt>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looked like it worked. But, when you actually place the content down, there is a space (between the Card Title and the image). [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMzQbj)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting challenge.

Below is a method which has the appearance of cropping each image to only its top height, but it requires that the frames containing each image still be the full height.

Note that I've rename what you called `div.img`s to `div.frame`s for clarity.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  height: 100vh;
}

.frame {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgrey; /* set transparent to make frames invisible */
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: block; /* default is inline-block, which adds extra space */
}

.frame + .frame {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.frame > img {
  /* this image expands the .frame to fit full image size */
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cropper {
  /* with parent .frame set to full image hight, 50% of .frame height is 50% of image hight */
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cropper img {
  /* inside the cropper, display the normal image—it'll overflow at 50% of its height */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="frame">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x550/009/fff.png" alt>
    <div class="cropper">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x550/009/fff.png" alt>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="frame">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/090/fff.png" alt>
    <div class="cropper">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/090/fff.png" alt>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="frame">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x150/09f/fff.png" alt>
    <div class="cropper">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x150/09f/fff.png" alt>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works by placing a full-height, *invisible* image within each `div.frame`. This "expands" each `div.frame` from the inside to match the full height of the image. Each `div.frame` then *also* contains an absolultey-positioned `div.cropper`, set to 50% of its parent container's height. Because our invisible image set our `div.frame` to the height of the image, this *is* 50% of the image's height, even as it scales. Finally, that `.cropper` contains our image again. Because `.cropper` is set to `overflow: hidden`, only the top 50% of the image is shown.

I've colored the `.frames` grey to illustrate what's going on. If you don't want the `.frame`s to be visible, you can simply set their `background-color: transparent` (or don't specifiy a `background-color`—`transparent` is the default).

You may be able to cut back on `<img>` elements and achieve the same effect using `background-image`, but I've yet to twist this method just right to find way that *doesn't* require the `.frame`s to remain full height while their contents are "chopped".