# How to make the image half height?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I made a list of images and tried to halve the height of this image.

```css
.img {
  background: #255;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x200/009/fff.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Image title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">description text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/550x768/009/fff.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Image title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">description text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used the transform property. This looked like it worked, but a hidden area was left between the image and the text. I want to realize the operation when this space is lost.

```css
.img {
  background: #255;
  transform: scaleY(0.5);
  transform-origin: top;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  transform: scaleY(2);
  transform-origin: top;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x200/009/fff.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Image title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">description text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/550x768/009/fff.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Image title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">description text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is the exposed area left as blank space? Also, how can I hide the overexposed area? How can I view an image that is only half the height of the image?

Comment: I am still thinking about it, didn't forget you :) (https://stackoverflow.com/q/55304008/8620333)

Comment: the *why* is due to the fact that transform doesn't affect the layout, it's only a visual transformation

Comment: So, the output will result in the image with half height and the card-text as it is or both cards with images and text with the same height?

Comment: it's an aside, but a `class="img"` is likely to leave you confused by your css later on in the project.  I'd suggest `class="img-wrapper"` to save you (or a future maintainer) a bit of confusion/frustration.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer each of your questions in order.

> Why is the exposed area left as blank space?

"transform: scaleY" is a style applied to the current element to define the height of the element to appear on the screen. It does not alter the amount of space on the screen allocated for that element.

So when you apply the transformation to the element (in this case the image) it is saying you only want to DISPLAY half of the elements height on the page, not change the element to 50% of its height.

Then you use "transform-origin: " which asks at which point on the element do you want to start displaying the element. You then select "top" which tells the webpage that you now want to display half of the element starting at the top. Which is why you see the top half of both images.

The blank space is the portion of the element that you specified you did not want to display. The element still has that half of the image there it is just not displayed so that is your blank space.

> Also, how can I hide the overexposed area?

To remove the exposed area all you have to do is remove the "transform: scaleY(0.5);" from the .img class style. This tells the webpage that you want to show the full height of the element as it is set back to its default of 1. The other "transform: scaleY(2)" should be maintained as now it will double the size of the img element within its parent elements initial height. The "overflow: hidden" will then hide that bottom half of the new image height.

> How can I view an image that is only half the height of the image?

This is fairly ambiguous so I will answer it under the assumption you want to only show the top half of the image of which you know the dimensions. For example with the 800x200 pixel image.

```
.img {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This just makes the container element half the height of the image so it will only show half of the image. The overflow of the other half of the image is hidden. Also the image will not resize to its container because of the max width being set to 100%.